# SSL Error while sending an ajax call with FormData object

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, form-data

I'm sending an ajax request.

```
  $.ajax({
            url: path,
            data: parameters,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: method,
            success: handler,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                ErrorsManager.showError(xhr);
                handler(null);
            }
        });
```

I'm sending this kind of a request because the object that I'm passing is an FormData object

For some reason, the SSL verification doesn't let this request to pass.
This is the error:

```
error":"error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I've a feeling it got something to do with the

> contentType=false

of the request.

Comment: Please provide more (relevant) code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in path you set wrong port number? For HTTPS with SSL it should be 443, for http - 80. Check this out in browser network log.